# Llenado automático de campo de textos de un formulario al colocar un código de base de datos. PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

recién estoy iniciándome en el mundo de la programación e inicie por php. Estoy realizando un formulario el cual tiene un campo (codigoclientebanco) el cual tenga un botón "consultar" que me rellene el campo "exportador" para luego proceder a guardar los datos con el botón "guardar" .Sin embargo, no encuentro la manera de rellenar automáticamente el campo "exportador" al presionar "consultar"*/,ya que por defecto me lleva a otra página al presionar.Entiendo que se puede hacer con Javascript pero quisiera un poco de orientación con ello. Les comparto el codigo que tengo.
Mi tabla maecliente solo tiene codigoclientebanco,nombrecliente

****index.php****

```
**<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registro</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="group">
  <form action="registro.php" method="POST">
  <h2><em>Formulario de Registro</em></h2>  
      <label for="fecha_d">Fecha de Desembolso <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="date" name="fecha_d" step="1" min="2018-01-01" max="2020-12-31" value="2018-01-01" required="">

      <label for="t_operacion">Tipo Operación <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="t_operacion" class="form-input" required/>   

      <label for="num_factura">N° Factura <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="num_factura" class="form-input" required/> 
      <label for="num_operacion">N° Operacion <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="num_operacion" class="form-input" required/> 
      <label for="num_cod_cliente">Codigo de cliente <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="num_cod_cliente" class="form-input" required/> 
      <Left> <input class="form-btn-consulta" name="consultar" type="submit" value="Consultar" /></left> 
        <!--<input type="text" class="loquesea" value="<?php echo $resultado['nombre']; ?>">   -->
      <label for="num_factura">Exportador<span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label>
      <input type="text" name="num_factura" class="form-input"   value= "<?php echo $consulta['CodigoClienteBanco']; ?>"  />   


     <center> <input class="form-btn" name="guardar" type="submit" value="Guardar" /></center>

    </p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>**
```

***registro.php***

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="financiero2017ic";
$db_name="web_factoring";
$db_table_name="factoring";
$db_table_name_2 = "maecliente";
 $db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

if (!$db_connection) {
    die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
}
$subs_fecha_d = utf8_decode($_POST['fecha_d']);
$subs_t_operacion = utf8_decode($_POST['t_operacion']);
$subs_num_factura = utf8_decode($_POST['num_factura']);
$subs_num_cod_cliente= utf8_decode($_POST['num_cod_cliente']);

//$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." WHERE Email = '".$subs_email."'", $db_connection);


//if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
//{

//header('Location: Fail.html');

//} else {

if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) { 


    $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`fecha_d` , `t_operacion` , `num_factura`) VALUES ("' . $subs_fecha_d . '", "' . $subs_t_operacion . '", "' . $subs_num_factura . '")';

mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);
$retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

if (!$retry_value) {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header('Location: Success.html');
} 



if (isset($_POST['consultar'])) { 

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);




    /*$select_value = "SELECT nombrecliente,nombrefuncionario,grupo,lider FROM maecliente where codigoclientebanco = $subs_num_cod_cliente" ; */
    /*mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection); */

     $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $db_table_name_2  WHERE codigoclientebanco = '$subs_num_cod_cliente'");
        while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
       {

         echo $consulta['CodigoClienteBanco']."<br>";
         echo $consulta['NombreCliente']."<br>";


        }





 /* mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);  */



} 




//}

mysql_close($db_connection);


?>


***success.html***


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>¡Información Completa!</title>
<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="group">
  <form action="registro.php" method="POST">
  <h2><em>¡Información Completa!</em></h2>

  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***estilos.css***

body {
    background: rgb(125,185,232); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 71%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(71%,rgba(125,185,232,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 71%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 71%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 71%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(125,185,232,1) 71%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 99%); /* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7db9e8', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
h2 {
    color: #000
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;

}
.group {
    border: 3px solid #999999;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    color: #006;
border-radius: 8px;
border-color:#036;

```
background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(209,238,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(209,238,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(209,238,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(209,238,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(209,238,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(209,238,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
```

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d1eeff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.contact-form {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;

}

/* Form input box style */
.form-input {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FF9;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

/* Focus style */
.form-input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #7fbbf9;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #7fbbf9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #7fbbf9;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #7fbbf9;
}

/* Error style */
.form-input:-moz-ui-invalid {
    border: 1px solid #e00;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #e00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #e00;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #e00;
}

.form-input.invalid {
    border: 1px solid #e00;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #e00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #e00;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 0 1px #e00;
}

/* Form submit button */
.form-btn {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 30px;
    font: bold 12px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #0d3d6a;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1d83e2;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1d83e2), to(#0d3d6a)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1d83e2, #0d3d6a); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1d83e2, #0d3d6a); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1d83e2, #0d3d6a); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #1d83e2, #0d3d6a); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #1d83e2, #0d3d6a);
    -pie-background:          linear-gradient(top, #1d83e2, #0d3d6a); /* IE6-IE9 */
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow:         inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-background-clip:    padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip:         padding-box;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

.form-btn:active {
    border: 1px solid #1d83e2;
    background-color: #0d3d6a;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0d3d6a), to(#1d83e2)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d3d6a, #1d83e2); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0d3d6a, #1d83e2); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d3d6a, #1d83e2); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #0d3d6a, #1d83e2); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #0d3d6a, #1d83e2);
    -pie-background:          linear-gradient(top, #0d3d6a, #1d83e2); /* IE6-IE9 */
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

```
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

}

label {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    color: #003;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.contact-form.frame {
    background-color: #444444;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 20px;
}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Trate de arreglar tu pregunta, pero es demasiado codigo. Se necesita tanto para replicar tu problema? donde de todo eso es que falla? por ejemplo, que tiene que ver el css aca? Podrias explicar un poco como intentaste hacer lo que queres hacer, y que querrias que hiciera, y que error encontras? y mostrar solo esa poricion de codigo?

Comment: No hay ningún problema que al presionar tu botón 'consultar' te mande a la pagina de "registro.php" ya que es un input type="submit" y te va a dirigir al archivo o página que le indiques a tu etiqueta Form en el action="", la manera de hacer lo que necesitas es mediante AJAX, puedes utilizar jQuery o JavaScript puro.